# Proof verification: $b_k$ is a limit point of $a_n$, $c$ is a limit point of $b_k$, then $c$ is limit point of $a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would be thankful if somebody could check my proof. Also suggestions improving the notations are highly welcome.

We have two sequences $(a_n)_{n \ge 0},(b_k)_{k \ge 0}$. For each $k \in \mathbb N_0$ $b_k$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ and $c$ is a limit point of $(b_k)_{k \ge 0}$. We need to show that $c$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$.

**Proof**

If $c$ is a limit point of $(b_k)_{k \ge 0}$, then there must be a sub-sequence $(b_{k_\ell})_{\ell > 0}$ such that $b_{k_\ell} \to c$.

Now we construct a sub-sequence $(a_{n_\ell})_{\ell > 0}$ as follows:

1. $\ell=1$: because $b_{k_1}$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$, there must be a sub-sequence $(a_{n_q})_{q > 0}\to b_{k_1}$, and there must be $q^*$ such that $a_{n_{q^*}} \in (b_{k_1}-1,b_{k_1}+1)$, we set $n_\ell=n_{q^*}$.
2. $\ell>1$: and for all preceding indices elements of the sub-sequence are chosen, because $b_{k_\ell}$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$, there must be a sub-sequence $(a_{n_q})_{q > 0}\to b_{k_\ell}$, and there must be $q^*$ such that $a_{n_{q^*}} \in (b_{k_1}-\frac{1}{\ell},b_{k_1}+\frac{1}{\ell})$ and $n_{q^*} > n_{\ell-1}$, we set $n_\ell=n_{q^*}$.

Now we show that $(a_{n_\ell})_{\ell>0}\to c$.

We take $\epsilon>0$, then $\exists L_1 : \forall \ell \ge L_1, \lvert c-b_{k_\ell}\rvert<\epsilon / 2$. Also $\exists L_2 : \forall \ell \ge L_2, \frac{1}{\ell}<\epsilon / 2$.

Now $\forall \ell \ge \max(L_1,L_2)$:

$$\lvert a_{n_\ell}-c\rvert \le \lvert a_{n_l}-b_{k_\ell}\rvert + \lvert b_{k_\ell}-c\rvert < \frac{1}{\ell} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$

So $c$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$.

Comment: I made a change: I personally (and believe I am not the only one) prefer $\ell$ to $l$ in $\LaTeX$, for readability reasons. The macro is `\ell`. (I also prefer $\varepsilon$ to $\epsilon$, but this is much more debatable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks correct, but cumbersome. Specifically, you "mix" $\varepsilon$-based arguments and more high-level sequential ones. While this is sometimes necessary, one of the main point of doing the second is to avoid to resort to the "low-level $\varepsilon$ stuff."

*I have the feeling that the subsequence definition here is not the simplest ways, and makes things more conceptually difficult. For the sake of an alternative proof, and because **sometimes** $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-type proofs are easier, I am giving below an argument of the latter kind.*

We need to show that
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall N \geq 0, \exists n_{\varepsilon,N} \geq N \text{ s.t. } \lvert a_{n_{\varepsilon,N}} - c \rvert \leq \varepsilon \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, and $N\geq 0$.

- Since $c$ is a limit point for $(b_n)_n$, there exists (for $\varepsilon' \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $N$) some $m_{\varepsilon',N}\geq N$ such that $\lvert b_{m_{\varepsilon',N}} - c \rvert \leq \varepsilon'$.
- Since $b_{m_{\varepsilon',N}}$ is a limit point for $(a_n)_n$, there exists (for $\varepsilon' \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $N'=m_{\varepsilon',N}$) some $r_{\varepsilon',N'}\geq N'$ such that $\lvert a_{r_{\varepsilon',N'}} - b_{m_{\varepsilon',N}} \rvert \leq \varepsilon'$.

By the triangle inequality, combining the two,
$$
\lvert a_{r_{\varepsilon',N'}} - c \rvert \leq \lvert a_{r_{\varepsilon',N'}} - b_{m_{\varepsilon',N}} \rvert+\lvert b_{m_{\varepsilon',N}} - c \rvert \leq \varepsilon'+\varepsilon' = \varepsilon
$$
and $r_{\varepsilon',N'} \geq N' = m_{\varepsilon',N} \geq N$. Taking $n_{\varepsilon,N} \stackrel{\rm def}{=} r_{\varepsilon',N'}$ concludes the proof.

Comment: Note that I tend to be over-verbose with my subscripts, to keep track of the dependencies (with regard to quantifiers). In my proof, none of the subscripts are actually necessary, they are just here for visual bookkeeping.